# >> Can not connect to any device in local network [Windows 10] <<

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, connection

I'm currently facing some issues with Windows 10. I noticed that I don't get any connection to servers inside my local network. I first noticed this when trying to connect to a small server application that is running on an ESP8266. Server Code is verified to work (so not a programming issue) and every other device inside the network (basically all are connected to my router's WLAN) can access the server without problems. I also can't reach my Raspberry PI (with Putty or TightVNC). I just don't get any connection. With every other device inside the network I have no problem connecting to the Raspberry.

However if I run an IP scanner, it finds all devices inside the network. So they are recognized by my Windows 10 computer. I just don't get any connection.
By the way: Internet connection works fine for all devices (also the Windows 10 computer). Also I don't use a guest network (devices are not isolated).

Long story short: It seems as if some network settings on my Windows 10 computer are not correct. I remember that some time ago I actually went through the settings of Windows 10 and changed a few things. But I sadly don't remember what it was. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Have a nice day
- Jannis

Comment: In Advanced Network Sharing Center, make sure Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing are both ON. In Start, Settings, Network, Status, make sure the Network Device is set for Private (not Public).   Close out, restart and test your connection.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I changed the settings and restarted the computer (Indeed I had it to public and both settings off). Sadly this didn't solve the issue. Still no connection to the Raspberry or the ESP Server.

Comment: One other setting in Windows 10, Advanced Network Sharing, All Networks is Public Folder sharing. Make that is OFF (but that is the normal default).   For the Server, try to map a drive:  NET USE X: \\server\foldershare and authenticate.  What numerical system error do you get?

Comment: Just tried the setting for all networks. Sadly doesn't work (Is already off). Regarding the server: I'm running a small webserver on the ESP8266. Not a storage server. So I guess that I won't be able to map any drive. It's a webserver application that I can open by typing it's ip address into a web browser. However the problem might be some sort of permission. If I try to connect to my Raspberry with Putty, I get the message: "Network Error: Permission denied". Every other device inside the network has no issues connecting to the Raspberry or accessing the web server.

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install :   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) select Run.

Comment: Hi. Just tried to do a Windows 10 repair installation. Problem sadly still the same. If I can't find any solution I maybe need to reinstall Windows entirely. However just something that I noticed: If I use the IP Scanner to scan for all devices inside my network, I can see their names but behind the name it says (for every device): domain_not_set.invalid. Maybe this has to do with the problem?

Comment: Given all you have tried, the only remaining step (other computers are working as expected) is to back up everything, and then install Windows 10 fresh. Ensure connections are working before installing much software

Comment: All right. A fresh installation of windows 10 seems to work fine. Just tried it. I can now connect to all network devices. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So I will post the answer and hopefully you will acknowledge it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried many things including a Windows 10 Repair Install that did not work. The only remaining step (other computers are working as expected) is to back up everything, and then install Windows 10 fresh. Ensure connections are working before installing much software .

This final method should work fine.